Using GATK4.2 to create .idx using IndexFeatureFile for multiple vcf files
I have used GATK script : gatk IndexFeatureFile --input sampleid_hc.g.vcf to create .idx files for individual vcf files. However I am trying to create a loop and submit as a slurm job to create .idx for 200 vcf files. The script I used for this is
for file in *.g.vcf; do ./gatk IndexFeatureFile -I ${file} -O ${file}.idx; done

When I do this, I keep getting an error saying bad substitution. Please assist.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you're running an older version of GATK you may need to specify the input using -F (re https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360037428111-IndexFeatureFile) e.g. for file in *.g.vcf; do ./gatk IndexFeatureFile -F "${file}" -O "${file}.idx"; done. Also, is this the exact command you're running? Not for f in *.g.vcf; do ... $file ... or for f in *.g.vcf.gz? Might be worth adding in an echo before the command to make sure you are 'finding' the files you want to find (e.g. for file in *.g.vcf; do echo "$file"; ./gatk IndexFeatureFile -I "${file}" -O "${file}.idx"; done)

What is the output of ls *.g.vcf in the directory you run the command from? Can your file names contain spaces? Does it work if you quote your variables correctly with for file in *.g.vcf; do ./gatk IndexFeatureFile -I "$file" -O "$file".idx; done? What is the exact error you get?

Thank you. I will try these suggestions
